# Resharper - Run Unit Tests Until Fail - How many times has it run?

Tags: resharper

I had a flaky test. I think, I fixed it.
Now the tests are running until they fail (using resharper).

Say I'd like it to success 100 times before I call the flakiness gone.

I know that I can just measure the time it takes to loop once and then multiply by 100.

But isn't the count of the actual number of iterations visible somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: I'd love to see this feature as well. Since I couldn't find it either, maybe it's worth contacting the [JetBrains support](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66432) and raising a feature request.

Comment: I filed [RSRP-493831](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-493831/Indicate-how-many-times-the-tests-have-been-run-when-running-until-failure), please upvote the feature request.